# How to remove duplicate one column in java?

Tags: java, sql

I have resultset with duplicate rows.But i need to remove the duplicate from only one column.Other columns need duplicates.

```
Table1 : productcode,productname
Table2 : A_itemcode ,A_itemname
Table3 : B_itemcode,b_itemname
Table4 : c_itemcode,c_itemname
```

Table2,table3,table4 values based on table1.There is possiable to get values for table2 is 2 rows but table table3 return values is may be 5 rows and table4 return values is 8 rows.

Because i did join these tables. So obviously i will get multiple rows.Now i want to display the seperately but without duplicate values.I mean product code may be duplicate but it should be a duplicate for item code.

Here itemcode should be unique , how to remove dublicate in one column in java ?

Comment: Which SQL are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

This sort of thing is done in SQL, not Java.

But you haven't defined what you want.  If you would like to see each itemcode exactly once, you can do that by grouping by itemcode.  Then you have to decide what you want to do with the group of records you will obtain for each itemcode.  This is called "aggregation".  You might want to see, e.g., the maximum value for each of those fields (sorted by whatever [collation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184391.aspx) your database is using):

```
SELECT itemcode, 
MAX(itemname), 
MAX(productcode), 
MAX(productname)
FROM table1
GROUP BY itemcode
ORDER BY itemcode
```

Alternatively, you might be interested in seeing a list of all of unique combinations of the four fields:

```
SELECT itemcode, 
itemname, 
productcode, 
productname
FROM table1
GROUP BY itemcode, itemname, productcode, productname
ORDER BY itemcode, productcode
```

Of course, this means that you may very well see itemcode 123 twice, once for productcode 456, and then again for productcode 789.

It all depends on what you're looking for.  Which you have to figure out and explain, if you want better assistance.  It is easier if you can show your tablestructure and some sample data, along with a listing of the desired output.

UPDATE

Based on your updated question, I gather you are joining on a single "code" that gives you multiple matches across four tables, but you wish to see the unique "name" associated with that code in each table.  That would call for something like this:

```
SELECT productcode, 
 productname, 
 A_itemname, 
 B_itemname, 
 C_itemname
FROM Table1
JOIN Table2 ON A_itemcode = productcode
JOIN Table3 ON B_itemcode = productcode
JOIN Table4 ON C_itemcode = productcode
GROUP BY productcode, 
 productname, 
 A_itemname, 
 B_itemname, 
 C_itemname
```

If this isn't what you were thinking about, please try explaining again.

Again, do this in SQL, not in Java.

Comment: I have edited the question , please look into that questions.